# Does this look like normal memory increase? or should I worry about this?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory

I decided to run my app through the xcode instruments. My app consists of a tableview with each cell linking to a different view. These "linked" views are all from the same class, just with different values for the subviews, (similar to a messaging board with different threads).

I noticed that as I open and closed views, my memory would increase very slightly each time. I tried the heapshots method and was able to produce the following screenshot:

[image]

Does this memory increase look like something I should worry about? Each lump would start when I opened the cell's "linked view", and the lump ended when I closed it, but you'll notice that the stable strips in between each lump increase each time. I took a look at the different generations and saw a variety of classes that I have never seen or worked with before, which leads me to believe that they're all coming from the various frameworks that my app is using, possibly? I have a sliding view controller made by someone else, and also my app's backend is being run by parse.com, which is heavily laced throughout the app.

Here's a screenshot of the some of the allocations in generation D, none of which seem familiar to me.

[image]

I suppose my first question is, should I worry about this? and If so, how would I go about dealing with it?

edit:  I'm a very novice software developer and don't fully understand this "under the hood" stuff that is occurring in the main loop of the application. Taking a look at the all the persistent allocations, I don't know where any of them are from, none of them seem familiar to me. Is this due to my inexperience to recognize them, or could these be from the frameworks that I am using that weren't developed by me?

Answer (score 2):

If the Valleys (dips) in the allocation graph stay the same you should be fine, However if each time you perform an action and the valleys raise you have a leak

From the WWDC session Video "Fixing Memory Issues", https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/

Comment: The valleys increase very slightly each time. It levels off after about 10 dips and the increase becomes almost negligible. Would you consider this a problem? Thank you for the video also, I'll be sure to take a look at it.

Comment: It really depends on how much and your typical user case, if it takes hours of focuses button pressing to get to a low memory state you should be fine. To be honest I've never been able to ship an app without a memory leak of some kind, complicated apps have complicated problems. However, I've always noted them down and hope that time and better, less leaky, 3rd party frameworks will come in time.

Comment: To reiterate the point that all complex apps will tend to have small memory leaks: *Cocoa* has small memory leaks (usually on the order of a few hundred bytes to 1k or so now and then). You can't fix those. But I'm seeing about 2MB of extra memory left over from Generation C. That seems concerning, and I'd dig into what's in that generation (you generally want to study the next-to-last generation; not the last one).